# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue measurable. Is $f \circ g$ Borel measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue measurable. Is $f \circ g$ Borel measurable?

I think that the answer to this question is no. I know that the hypothesis implies that $f \circ g$ is Lebesgue measurable, but I am sure that there is a counter-example to show that $f \circ g$ is not Borel measurable, since the Borel sigma algebra is a proper subset of the Lebesgue sigma algebra.

**Note:** In my textbook, a function is measurable with respect to a sigma algebra $\mathcal{E}$ if and only if $[f > \alpha] = \{x : f(x) > \alpha\} \in \mathcal{E}$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

My current idea is to find a Lebesgue measurable set $D$ that is not Borel measurable. Then define $g(x) = \chi_{_{D}}$, which is Lebesgue measurable, as $D$ is Lebesgue measurable. Then $f(x) = x$ is continuous and $f \circ g = g$, but $g$ is not Borel measurable.

Comment: Does $X=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: I think your idea is a good one!

Comment: Your current idea is correct.